# 'continue' parameter in wikipedia API request

Tags: python, wikipedia-api

I'm struggling with the `continue` parameter of the wikipedia API that is not (yet) properly described in the [documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query).

I have pieced together a query in the API sandbox:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&format=json&list=exturlusage&meta=siteinfo&continue=-%7C%7Csiteinfo&formatversion=2&eucontinue=ftp%3A%2F%2FV4.129.71.206.174.%2Fcounty_maps%2FHarrison_2_of_2.pdf%7C38758224

What I couldn't figure out so far where the `eucontinue` parameter comes from as it doesn't appear to feature in the previous response.

What I'd like to do is to simply run a query that yields more than 500 results and collect the responses.

What has to be done, I guess, is to use the following code snippet in a loop while feeding an appropriate `CONTINUE` value in each iteration. Which value though?

```py
import requests

endpoint = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php"
p = {
    "action": "query",
    "format": "json",
    "list": "exturlusage",
    "meta": "siteinfo",
    "continue": "-||siteinfo",
    "formatversion": "2",
    "eucontinue": CONTINUE
}

res = requests.get(endpoint, params = p)
url = res.url
content = res.content
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Multiple parameters might need to be updated for the next request, as there can be multiple things that need to be continued (e.g. you can use `list=exturlusage|backlinks` and then you receive two lists "in parallel). The correct way to do it is to merge the returned `continue` parameter, ie. something like

```
p.update(res.continue)
```